# ld: find absolute paths to shared objects

Tags: linker, ld

I'm trying to debug a linker error, how can I make GNU `ld` "resolve" library names I pass it to absolute paths to the shared objects that are actually linked against? I.e. `-lfoo` -> `/usr/lib/foo.so.1` or similar.

Comment: XY problem? Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Because I think I might be linking against the wrong versions of several libraries and this would be the simplest way of debugging that as far as I can see.

Comment: You can add `-t` to the linker arguments to print filenames as they are processed, but they are not absolute paths. ld doesn't care about absolute paths. You can resolve them yourself.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But resolve them how? Just go through the ld search path? That's exactly what I would like to not do manually.

Comment: Just try it and see what it does.